# Why is this F# lazy expression being called multiple times?

Tags: f#

In the following code, I expected that the expression in my lazy computation would only be called once. (I expected that the cities would only be loaded once.)

```
type MyDataClass() = 
    static member Cities = lazy ( 
        printfn "Loading cities..."
        [ "Raleigh"; "Durham"; "Chapel Hill" ]
     )

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =
    printfn "%A" MyDataClass.Cities.Value
    printfn "%A" MyDataClass.Cities.Value
    0
```

When, in fact, the following output shows that the cities are loaded twice.

```
lazy-test/> dotnet run
Loading cities...
["Raleigh"; "Durham"; "Chapel Hill"]
Loading cities...
["Raleigh"; "Durham"; "Chapel Hill"]
```

**Why is the expression in my lazy computation being called more than once?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lazy expression is evaluated more than once because the static property of your class returns a new lazy instance every time it is accessed. That is, the lazy computation is compiled into a `get_Cities()` method. Every time you get the value of that property, a new `Lazy<string list>` instance is returned. Each newly returned `Lazy<string list>` has not been evaluated yet.

Here are some alternatives to the incorrect code:

```
// use an auto-implemented property
type MyDataClass() = 
    static member val Cities = lazy ( 
        printfn "Loading cities..."
        [ "Raleigh"; "Durham"; "Chapel Hill" ]
    )

// use a module and a value
module MyDataModule =
    let Cities = lazy ( 
        printfn "Loading cities..."
        [ "Raleigh"; "Durham"; "Chapel Hill" ]
     )
```

Comment: Why are you answering your own question and addressing yourself in second person?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Funny... I had not noticed that I used second person. I suppose it is a habit to answer questions on SO using second person. Do you think that is bad form? Should I change it?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307804/should-i-answer-my-own-question-in-second-person-or-in-first-person

Comment: You can still use `static` with automatically implemented properties, so you don't need to switch it to an instance property if you don't want to.

Comment: @kvb Thanks! I edited the answer to use a static, auto-implemented property instead of an instance property.